# Python argparse.ArgumentParser cannot differentiate between `--modes` and `--mode`

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

In this example script

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--modes', help="test", nargs='+', type=str)

args = parser.parse_args()
write_mode = args.modes
print(write_mode)
```

There is only one argument `modes`.

However, `python test.py --modes sdfsf` and `python test.py --mode sdfsf` give me the same output (`['sdfsf']`) which means the `parser` treats `mode` as `modes`.

Is this a bug of `argparse`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an example of [prefix matching](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argument-abbreviations-prefix-matching), which is allowed by argparse by default.

Turn it off by using `argparse.ArgumentParser(..., allow_abbrev=False)`.